# AspnetCore.Mvc Upload file error, the var caminho always null even with IFormfile valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I try upload a image, but var root is always null...

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Vinhoid,Nome,Ano,Teoralcool,Produtorid,Tipoid,Regiaoid,Datacriacao,Localimagem,Garrafid,Descricao,Preco,Stock")] VinhoDistribuicao vinhoDistribuicao, IFormFile Localimagem)
{
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("TipoUtilizador") == "Garrafeira")




    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           if (_context.Vinho.Any(x => x.Ano == vinhoDistribuicao.Ano && x.Nome == vinhoDistribuicao.Nome && x.Tipoid == vinhoDistribuicao.Tipoid) == false)

           {

                var caminho = Path.Combine(he.WebRootPath + "/ImageFiles",
                    Path.GetFileName(Localimagem.FileName));

                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(caminho, FileMode.Create);
                Localimagem.CopyTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
```

HTML

```
@model Lab4_Vinhos6.Models.VinhoDistribuicao

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Localimagem" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Localimagem" type="file" accept=".png, .jpg" class="form-control" value="" />

    <span asp-validation-for="Localimagem" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
var caminho = Path.Combine(he.WebRootPath + "/ImageFiles",
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `ImageFiles` folder in wwwroot. Then try to use below code

```
var caminho = Path.Combine(he.WebRootPath, "ImageFiles",Path.GetFileName(Localimagem.FileName));
```